Find distance between two nodes along a path
I'm trying to calculate the distance between two nodes but I can't find a solution:
int index = agent.getTransporter().getIndex(); //Find the transporter
Position posizioneTransportatore = main.aGVs.get(index).getPosition(); //Find the transporter position
Position posizioneLotto = agent.getPosition();  //Find the product position

//Find the nearest node from transporter and the nearest node from product
Network network = main.network;
Node startNode = network.getNearestNode(posizioneTransportatore.getX(),posizioneTransportatore.getY(),posizioneTransportatore.getZ(),null);
Node pickupNode = network.getNearestNode(posizioneLotto.getX(),posizioneLotto.getY(),posizioneLotto.getZ(),null);`

Thank you for the help
Source image
I did a lot of different trials, using ChatGPT or Java documentation

Have you tried unit.distanceTo(agent) in the code box? IIRC, if both agents are inside the network, distanceTo is done across the network from node to node
